# How to use FilterBy Method in Extjs local store

Tags: extjs, sencha-architect

Im new to Extjs 7.6 and using Sencha Architect.
I changed a remote filtered store to a local store.

How do i use the filterBy function in my controller?
I have read some examples but dont really understand.

The value is given by an input field.

Following my remote filter method:

```
application.getStore('ServiceStore').filter(
     [{id: 'number', property: 'number', value: value, operator: 'LIKE', andor:'OR'},
     {id: 'description', property: 'description', value: value, operator: 'LIKE', andor:'OR'}]
);
```

How to translate this to a local filterBy method?

Comment: Have you tried filtering the same way as before changing from remote to local? I think it should work the same way.

Comment: Unfortunately, this doesnt work. Extjs has no option for "OR", so its always "AND"... ive solved it with a filter function. (answer below)

Comment: What do you want to do exactly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found the answer:

```
store = application.getStore('ServiceStore');
store.filter(new Ext.util.Filter({
    filterFn: function(item) {
        if (item.data.number.indexOf(value) > -1 || item.data.description.indexOf(value) > -1) {
            return true;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }
}));
```